# Expression for advantages of solution being disadvantages of alternatives

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

Is there some expression for situations where you can conclude that a solution's advantages are the same as the disadvantages of alternative solutions?

Comment: As Jasper notes, if you give us a real example you might see answers that might be more interesting to you.

Comment: I mean situations when there are two choices and the pros of one are the cons of the other and vice versa. So what I'd like to emphasize is that the choise is not between the named alternatives, but the mutually exclusive properties they have.

Comment: @Tihamer, do you realize that you just described something essentially different? Also, you have not provided an example - your quest for the answer will be much easier if you illustrate the situation with example or analogy.

Comment: @Unreason Yes indeed, I'm sorry for the confusion. An example I like is what Hackworth already posted below.

Comment: "mutually exclusive" has a related meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be a bit verbose and humorous, you could just repeat the fact verbatim and put the sentence as if it was a clear example/counterexample.

Example: You sell your car and do all your traveling by bicycle. That is environmentally friendly and your personal health benefits. On the other hand, shopping and quick, long-distance mobility is limited.

So you could say:

> On the one hand, I sold my car. 
>   On the other hand, I sold my car!

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially, we might say

> It's six of one, half a dozen of the other.

or

> It's a wash.

or more technically,

> There's no net benefit.

or

> The net benefit is zero.

Substitute other nouns for *benefit* at will.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is such an expression, however you may say that 'the advantages do not outweigh the disadvantages'.

Answer (score 0):

The word I would use is *balanced.*

As in, "The pros and cons of the action were balanced."

Answer (score 0):

kif kif, a good one is:

**The front is as big as the back**.

there are many sayings of this nature in English, most are mentioned in the other answers. That's my favourite one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on the case.

Case "software":

> .NET's reflection is **just as good** as Java's reflection.

Case "family":

> My girlfriend's dog was **just as bad** as her former one.

Answer (score -1):

*Double-edged sword* or *two-edged sword*.